# Using two wifi dongles at the same time

Tags: wifi

Here's my situation:

I am using a Raspberry Pi to control a system.  I want to allow the system to be changed over the internet as well as locally.
My current plan for controlling it locally is to connect a laptop to it in some way in order to adjust settings.

I have found that it is possible to create an ad-hoc wireless network with the pi. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/04/22/raspberry-pi-wireless-communication/

This sounded like the ideal solution for local control because then one could change the system locally using virtually anything with wifi.

So, I tried hooking up two wifi dongles (both Edimax) and configure them so that one can connect to a wifi network and the other can be responsible for the ad-hoc wireless network. However, there appears to be some issues with this. While I can connect to a wireless network, the ad-hoc network only appears in my laptop's list of wireless connections sporadically.
When only hooking up one wifi dongle and configuring it to be an ad-hoc network, the ad-hoc network appears in my laptop's list of wireless connections more consistently.

Has anyone tried something like this before and succeeded?  Even if I did manage to do this, I don't know how I would differentiate between them in the program sending/receiving things over those connections. Is using two dongles even possible with the Pi's hardware?

**Edit per comments:**

I'm currently powering the pi with my laptop USB port. I'll give it a try with my phone charger in a couple hours. Also, this is a Raspberry pi 2 with four USB ports so I am not using a hub....they are plugged directly in.

To clarify, I want the program on the Pi to:

- Be able to send/receive info from the ad-hoc network using wifi dongle 1(to allow for a computer to connect to it directly and control the device)
- Be able to send/receive info from the internet using wifi dongle 2 (to allow the device to be controlled remotely over the internet)
- The most likely candidate for doing all of this at the moment is nod.js

Here is my current /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  wireless-channel 1
  wireless-essid RPiAdHocNetwork
  wireless-mode ad-hoc

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Two wifi dongles will eat a lot of power, and I'm wondering if the intermittency is partially caused by that. Are they attached using an external hub? If not, how powerful is your power supply?

Comment: The ad-hoc tutorial you quoted is very old, and predates the latest Raspbian. It is certainly possible to use 2 WiFi dongles, but you have not clearly specified exactly what you are trying to achieve, or how the network is configured.

Comment: You may have added a bit more, but still haven't explained why you think you need 2 connections. I can't see why you want an ad-hoc connection. If you can connect to the Pi over the internet, why not just connect from your laptop over the network using a single dongle. Normally an ad-hoc connection is used when there is no other network, or to share an internet connection.

Comment: I am doing the Ad-hoc network because I am not always guaranteed to have an internet connection.  If for instance, the internet is down, I need an alternate way to control the device.

Comment: If you are only powering the Pi via the micro-USB port, there is almost no way you will be able to provide enough power for both of the dongles and the Pi. I hate to say it, but you need a powered USB hub.

Comment: I will give it another try. You still haven't described your network configuration. Is the Pi connected to a router (even if no internet)? Is the laptop connected to a network?

Comment: I will also reiterate Milliways point - your broadband modem/route has two **independent** functions and the second - the router will operate *even if there is no broadband connection through the modem* {though my cable-modem/router can have the second function turned off to only provide a wired connection to the modem through the first LAN port - which is a useful thing given that the dual-band wireless can only practically do one band at a time - so the ability to hook up a decent external wire/wireless switch is a useful option! 8-) }

Comment: I suppose one *possible* usage case *might* be if you wanted a separate Wireless **D**e**M**ilititarised **Z**one on the Ad-hoc link for a LAN gaming night with your friends but did not trust them fully to not to try snooping around your own LAN for a prawn collection featuring yourself and your significant other.  You would want to be sure of your firewall/forwarding set-up!

Comment: Thanks all for your advice.  I decided to go with another method to accomplish things.  Going to just do the communication through a serial connection instead.